# Display staggered kind of list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

In my application i want data to be shown in a list.The layout will be staggered.For this i am using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayout, but still i am not getting the desired effect.Please help me to achieve this.

List row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="05dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#861e1e"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="New Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ListActivity

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private List<String> list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_with_pager);

        inflateViews();


    }

    @Override
    protected void inflateViews() {

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_lvp_main);
        //GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(5, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new StaggeredAdapter(this, getList()));

    }
```

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Well i will suggest you to use this library 
[Android Tag Group](https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup)

add one class in your project and give reference in xml file

[TagGroup.java](https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/gujun/android/taggroup/TagGroup.java)